# IBM BPM 8.6 :: Unable to reassign back to group

Tags: websphere, business-process-management

We're working with IBM BPM 8.6.
In many workflows, we do the typical team assignment. The users can claim the task, and work with it. But there is a problem, they cannot assign the task back to the group within the Process Portal.

All we get is a tooltip with the "This action is not permitted" when we try to reassign back to the group.

Reassign back to group disabled image

[image: (Reassign back to group disabled image)]

The same happens if we try to reassign it to an specific user:

Reassign to user disabled image

[image: (Reassign to user disabled image)]

We know that we could add the following instruction to the workflows:

```
tw.system.currentTask.reassignBackToRole()
```

to reassign it back,
but this would affect all the projects, and it would require time and resources to do so.

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the "action policies" for the Portal (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8JB4_19.x/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.doc/topics/restricting_access_to_portal_functions.html). I searched for "process portal action policies" to find the linked page (IBMs URLs can be pretty transient).

The one you're interested in is "ACTION_REASSIGN_TASK". This should be available to all users by default so perhaps it has been changed. You can use was_admin to change or check the values e.g.

```
wsadmin>AdminConfig.modify(getBPMPolicyAction("ACTION_REASSIGN_TASK"), [["roles", "newrole"]])
wsadmin>AdminConfig.save()
```